# Origin of for( ; ; ) in C?

Tags: c

Why do some people use `for( ; ; )` in c instead of just using `while(1`)? Is there some sort of speed advantage? I cannot for the life of me find a reason to do it other than to make the code harder to read

Comment: It doesn't require any magic literals, which is nice.

Comment: It depends on personal style, no speed advantage...

Comment: My guess is that they use the `for( ; ; )` to be able to put in expressions later if they want the loop modified. AFAIK there is no performance difference.

Comment: I think advocating while(1) for clarity is strange, when you could write while(true) instead.

Comment: There is no functional difference. I do not have access to a compiler at the moment to prove it, but I would bet they produce identical assembly.

Comment: Idiom my friend, [Idiom](http://www.labri.fr/perso/strandh/Teaching/MTP/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/idioms.html)

Comment: @Eiko: `true` didn't exist in C prior to C99. In C99 and later, it exists only if you've added `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Why do some people use `while(1)` in C instead of just using `for(;;)`?